# Hibernate join fetch not giving all child records

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, jpql, hibernate-mapping

As I am using HQL queries with join fetch. When I am using group by with parent id, Then I am not getting single child record. If I didn't use the group by, then I am getting all child records.
But if I didn't use group by I am getting duplicate parent records. Can you please help me how to get all child records with group by.

**Edit 1**

**Query without Group by**

```
select distinct itinerary from Itinerary itinerary 
   join fetch itinerary.customer customer 
   left join fetch customer.rewardProgram 
   left join fetch customer.customerContactDetails 
   left join fetch customer.customerPreferredAirlines 
   left join fetch itinerary.couponHistory 
   left join fetch itinerary.rewardUsageData 
   left join fetch itinerary.itineraryCancellationDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.insuranceDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.customerTravelRequest  
   left join fetch itinerary.flightSegments flightSegments 
   left join fetch itinerary.employeeEmployerDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.customerGSTClaimDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.itineraryExtension 
   left join fetch itinerary.itineraryGSTDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.itnerariesTravlersAssosciation assosciation 
   left join fetch assosciation.traveler
   where (itinerary.status IN ('BOOK','CONFIRM')) 
     AND (itinerary.id,flightSegments.arrivalTime) IN 
       (select flightSegments.itinerary,flightSegments.arrivalTime 
          from flightSegments where flightSegments.arrivalTime >= ?2) 
     AND customer.id = ?1 AND itinerary.companyId = :companyId 
  ORDER BY itinerary.bookingDate DESC
```

**Query with Group By**

```
select distinct itinerary from Itinerary itinerary 
   join fetch itinerary.customer customer 
   left join fetch customer.rewardProgram 
   left join fetch customer.customerContactDetails 
   left join fetch customer.customerPreferredAirlines 
   left join fetch itinerary.couponHistory 
   left join fetch itinerary.rewardUsageData 
   left join fetch itinerary.itineraryCancellationDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.insuranceDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.customerTravelRequest  
   left join fetch itinerary.flightSegments flightSegments 
   left join fetch itinerary.employeeEmployerDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.customerGSTClaimDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.itineraryExtension 
   left join fetch itinerary.itineraryGSTDetails 
   left join fetch itinerary.itnerariesTravlersAssosciation assosciation 
   left join fetch assosciation.traveler 
   where (itinerary.status IN ('BOOK','CONFIRM')) 
     AND (itinerary.id,flightSegments.arrivalTime) IN 
       (select flightSegments.itinerary,flightSegments.arrivalTime 
          from flightSegments where flightSegments.arrivalTime >= ?2) 
     AND  customer.id = ?1 AND itinerary.companyId = :companyId 
   group by flightSegments.itinerary.id 
   ORDER BY itinerary.bookingDate DESC
```

Comment: Use the correct query :) - Seriously, without any code and maybe an example containing input data and output you expect/get it's hard to help other than making vague suggestions. You might want to read [ask] and try to put yourself in our spot: would you know what to do with as little information as you've provided?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry , my bad, I have updated my question with queries. Can you please check once.

Comment: Those are some quite complex queries... One thing that immediately springs to my mind: you have multiple `left join fetch` which as far as I know has 2 "issues": 1) a fetch join doesn't need `left` etc. and this is probably ignored and 2) Hibernate used to have problems with multiple fetch joins, especially if they are nested.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read up on what a fetch join is: it's a SQL join (which has no fetch) but JPA will ignore the result in its query. Nevertheless all those fetch joins will create a cartesian product which means `itinerary` is duplicated. If you use `distinct` as well as `group by` you'll truncate the result of that product which in turn won't include all the child records.

Thus I'd suggest you go with the first query and filter the duplicates by putting them into a `LinkedHashSet` so you can maintain the order the query returns them in.
This of course required proper implementation of `equals()` and `hashCode()` which I assume you know already.

Example:

```
List<Itinerary> queryResult = ...;

Set<Itinerary> uniqueItineraries = new LinkedHashSet<>();
for( Itinerary itinerary : queryResult ) {
  uniqueItineraries.add(itinerary);
}

List<Itinerary> filteredList = new ArrayList<>(uniqueItineraries);
```

In any case this query seems to load an aweful lot of data in one go so you might want to rethink your options, e.g. why not load the itineraries without their children and fetch the children separately when necessary. I'd assume that most of this data won't be displayed in a larger listing anyway.